# Installing Spotify

Tags: command-line, software-installation, spotify

Hi everyone I'm attempting to install spotify, I've been running linux for less than 24 hours so please cut me some slack if this seems trivial. Here is a link to the webpage https://www.spotify.com/us/download/previews/ and the example script.

> 1. Add this line to your list of repositories by editing your `/etc/apt/sources.list`
>
>    ```
>    deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
>    ```
> 2. If you want to verify the downloaded packages, you will need to add our public key
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 94558F59
>    ```
> 3. Run apt-get update
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get update
>    ```
> 4. Install spotify!
>
>    sudo apt-get install spotify-client

would someone be nice enough to walk me through this? I'm not even sure where to start.

Comment: @guntbert Why did you remove the blockquote?

Comment: @dericke The blockquote is used for **quoting** text (opposed to one's own text).

Comment: @guntbert Which is what the text I blockquoted is. A quote from the page that the asker linked.

Comment: @dericke you are right, I overlooked that fact. Strangely I am not able to roll back my edit now.

Answer (score 12):

Open your favorite terminal, or just any.

`ctrl + alt +t` should open the default terminal, if not, search for terminal in the application menu.

Paste in

```
echo 'deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free' | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list
```

It will ask for your user password, just type it in (you can't see the characters, but it's there, just type and press enter when done.)

Then paste

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 94558F59
```

And then, guess what, paste in (we'll combine the two last commands here)

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

You can paste in the terminal with `ctrl + shift + v`, right click or by right clicking and selecting paste, depending on the terminal.

If you're running 15.04, running spotify-client will probably cause whining about missing dependencies, here's a [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/04/fix-missing-libgcrypt11-causing-spotify.html) about that.

If the link goes dead, I've included the basic stuff from that below.

[Download if your system is 32-bit](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_i386.deb)

[Download if your system is 64-bit](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb)

Then navigate to where ever you downloaded said files, and run

```
sudo dpkg -i libcrypt11*
```

And you should be up and running before you can say streichholzschächtelchen.

Comment: Awesome! worked perfectly, so i'm guessing "echo" tells it to go to the website? Is this portion of the first line "| sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list" going to remain constant between all installations?

Comment: No, echo means to write the following string. I used it instead of telling you to open a file manually, add the line and save the file. | basically means to take that output and do the following command with said output.

Comment: Also note that the line that was printed to the file didn't have a line break in it, so you'll have to edit the file manually next time you add to it, or prepend \n before the deb part.

Comment: This information is extremely out of date.  I've updated the information with my answer.

Comment: 15.04 is actually EOL so that info is irrelevant.

Comment: I'd recommend using the official instructions, and search for alternatives if they don't work: https://www.spotify.com/fi/download/linux/

Comment: I get the following errors

jacob@jacob-linux ~ $ sudo apt-get install spotify-client
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/packages.linuxmint.com_dists_rosa_upstream_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Answer (score 3):

Spotify is now available as a [snap](https://snapcraft.io/spotify) so you can find it in Ubuntu Software, or install in a terminal with one command:-

```
snap install spotify
```

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal using `ctrl + alt + t`. Type (or paste) in

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys BBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19
```

Next, type:

```
echo deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
```

Finally just type

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install spotify-client.
```

This does work in 16.04. Previous version only worked 15.10 and earlier.