# How do I install Spotify in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, spotify

There seems to be a lot of problems with installing Spotify in 16.04. I tried this guide [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624527/installing-spotify) to make sure I wasn't just screwing up, but it never worked. Turns out, this question is a little out-dated. To help out new users, I'll ask the question, give some information, then answer this.

I'm trying to install spotify in Ubuntu 16.04. I tried a few different guides. Here's the steps I've done in the previously mentioned guide. First, I pasted in

```
echo 'deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free' | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then I added the key using:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 94558F59
```

Finally I updated and tried installing Spotify using

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

Comment: Are you answering a question that no one has asked yet? Would it not make more sense to post your answer on the original spotify installation question with a notation that it applies to 16.04? If we all started posting answers to problems we solved for ourselves each day this website would get cluttered quickly.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix The previous answer has an already  accepted answer. Unless there's a way to mark questions as "out of date" then people like myself wouldn't scroll down through all the answers. If the accepted answer doesn't work I just move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the answer is super simple! Everything in what you did was right except for the key you added! Replace

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 94558F59
```

with

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys BBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19886
```

and follow the rest of the steps the same! If you need all the updated steps, you can find them [here](https://www.spotify.com/us/download/linux/)

Answer (score 2):

Spotify is now available as a [snap](https://snapcraft.io/spotify) so you can find it in Ubuntu Software, or install in a terminal with one command:-

```
snap install spotify
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the key in the command `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys BBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19886`
 I got the following warning when installing *spotify-client*:

"WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!"

[www.spotify.com/us/download/linux](https://www.spotify.com/us/download/linux/) gives the following code to use for the key: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 0DF731E45CE24F27EEEB1450EFDC8610341D9410`

This worked and allowed a successful install of spotify-client without any warnings, when following the other steps in the original question. Running Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit.